# I want to send an observable up 2 parent components. How would I do this? Would I need to use an EventEmitter?

Tags: angular, angular2-observables, eventemitter

I have a page component, a list component and a detail component (parent to child hierarchy: page->list->detail) and I'm trying to get an observable in the detail component up to the page component through component sharing.

I've tried doing this by putting the observable in an EventEmitter and sending it upward, however, it doesn't seem to be working. It could be one of two things: I'm incorrectly sending the observable up, or I'm correctly sending the observable up and I'm incorrectly extracting it from the EventEmitter. The code looks something like this.

Detail component:

```
@Output() outputHumidityWarning$ = new EventEmitter<Observable<boolean>>();
...
ngOnInit() {
  this.outputHumidityWarning$.emit(this.humidityWarning$);
}
```

Where humidityWarning$ is of type Observable

List component template:

```
<app-detail (outputHumidityWarning$)="inputHumidityWarning($event)"</app-detail>
```

List component:

```
private humidityWarning = new Replaysubject<boolean>(1);
...
ngOnInit() {
  this.humiditywarning.subscribe(all => console.log(all));
}
...
inputHumidityWarning = function (humidityWarning) {
  this.humidityWarning = humidityWarning;
}
```

I've also tried:

```
inputHumidityWarning = function (humidityWarning) {
  this.humidityWarning.next(humidityWarning);
}
...
inputHumidityWarning = function (humidityWarning) {
  this.humidityWarning.next(of(humidityWarning));
}
```

No errors but I won't get anything on the console.
When I console.log this.humidityWarning after setting it, I'll get an AnonymousSubject. This is why I tried wrapping it an of().
When I console.log(humidityWarning) I'll get an EventEmitter

Comment: If my solution doesn't solve your issue let me know to delete my answer, as well as if you can provide stackblitz link for it, people can help you better

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding your objective, but I have accomplished similar component communication a different way.  For example consider application state that may need to be shared among multiple components.

I typically create a service that exposes an observable and implements Behavior Subject as both an observer and observable.  Then I can inject the service into the into components like your child component as an input and subscribe to the service in other components that need to observe, like your parent component. I usually define the observable in the services with a defined type using an interface to keep it.

Here is an example I created to manage search parameters that were updated by various components.

The service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { SearchParams, Filter } from '../components/searchParam/searchparams.entity';
import { ISearchParams } from '../components/searchParam/searchparams.interface';
import { parkDetails } from '../services/getParkDetails.service';


@Injectable()
export class searchParamStateService {
    private _searchParamSource: BehaviorSubject<ISearchParams>;
    searchParams: Observable<ISearchParams>;
    private dataStore: ISearchParams;

    constructor() {    
        this.dataStore = new SearchParams('', [],[],[]);
        this._searchParamSource = new BehaviorSubject<ISearchParams>(this.dataStore);
        this.searchParams = this._searchParamSource.asObservable();        
    }


    // called when the searchtextbox is updated in search component
    changeSearchString(searchString: string) {
        this.dataStore.SearchString = searchString;
        this._searchParamSource.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore));
    }


    setXYParams(lat, long) {  
        //console.log('searchparamstate.service setXYParams: ' + lat + '  ' + long);
        this.dataStore.SearchX = lat;
        this.dataStore.SearchY = long;
        this._searchParamSource.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore));

    }

}
```

Then in components I can observe or contribute to the state:

```
//inject service into component

...

searchstateService.data.subscribe(data => {
  //do what ever needs doing when data changes
})

...

//update the value of data in the service
searchstateService.changeSearchString('new search string);
```

Comment: Yeah I thought about using a service for this. Is there anyway to send an arbitrary amount of observables from the detail component to the service then back into the parent (list) component without the observables overwriting eachother?

Comment: Can you give me an example of the desired behavior.  Are all of the observables you are referring to of the same type?   I imagine a parent component (list) with multiple details components.     Each detail item in the list needs to bubble a humidity warning up to the parent? Then what?  I ask because I don't think you should need to send an "arbitrary amount of observables".  That just seems convoluted.

Comment: Remember observables can deliver multiple values of any type.  For example you could expose one observable that consists of a  variable length list of humidity warnings like -   humidityWarning: Observable<List<IHumidityWarning>>;

Comment: Also remember that angular is reactive and subjects emit event streams which basically consist of a sequence of values over time. The stream consists of every state of the subject that has ever existed.  Meaning that if you reset a property of a subject it doesn't exactly overwrite the value, it creates a new state to add to the sequence, if you just need to know all of the emitted warnings you could leverage the reactive nature of the Subject to replay the warnings.

Comment: The subject.asObservable creates a subject that can add to an event stream and is also observable by subscribers.
here is a good resource on the topic:
https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-extensive-guide-to-creating-streams-in-rxjs-aaa02baaff9a

Comment: So I decided to change the layout of my page and where I need the information so I don't need an answer to this anymore, but thank you for the help!!